# Persistence unit not injected in webservice

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jax-ws

I have an application that was working on Java 6 + Glassfish 3. I am migrating this project to run on Glassfish 5.1 with oracle java 8.

The application builds without problems. During deployment the only jpa/eclipselink related lines are

```
Info:   EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a
Info:   /file:/home/eelke/NetBeansProjects/MplusLicentieService/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/_MplusLicentieServicePU login successful
```

However when a soap call is performed a `NullPointerException` is triggered. I have verified with the debugger that the pointer that is null is in fact the persistence unit. Here is the definition of the webservice, the EntitiyManager and one of the methods that failed. Within the method `em == null`. Left out other statements and variables.

```
@WebService(serviceName = "LicentieWebService")
public class LicentieWebService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MplusLicentieServicePU")
    private EntityManager em;
    @Resource
    private javax.transaction.UserTransaction utx;

    @WebMethod(operationName = "getLicentie2")
    public QLicentieAntwoord getLicentie2(
            @WebParam(name = "licentieNr") String licentieNr,
            @WebParam(name = "filiaalNr") int filiaal,
            @WebParam(name = "werkplekNr") int werkplek,
            @WebParam(name = "codewoord") String codewoord) {
        try {
            Licentie lic = em.find(Licentie.class, licentieNr);
            ...
        } catch (ApplicationError ex) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

I also tried redefining the persistence unit in netbeans but this didn't change anything.

**Some additional findings**

In the same project is also a statelesss EJB which has a function that is called by a timer schedule. Into this EJB a second stateless EJB is injected with @Inject, this works. Into this second EJB the same persistent context is injected as in the webservice. This works, it is injected and queries are executed as expected.

**Found some log lines which might be related**

> Info:   JAX-WS RI specific descriptor (WEB-INF/sun-jaxws.xml) is found
>   in the archive web and  hence Enterprise Web Service (109) deployment
>   is disabled for this archive to avoid duplication of services.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137385/persistence-xml-with-glassfish-3-1-1

Comment: @perissf, nothing in that question and answers that helps me. Resources and pools have been created corrected in glassfish and name matches persistence.xml. As soon as I break something there I also get error about it in glassfish log. But I'm getting no errors, the em is just not injected.

Comment: Ok, and the WebService is not instantiated manually somewhere in your code I suppose. Its lifecycle is supposed to be managed by the web/application container

Comment: @perissf, correct it is managed by the container. Note I also added some additional findings to my question.

Comment: @perissf, never mind I have it working, thought I'm not certain what was wrong. After so many tries I reset to last commit and re-resolved the missing dependencies and now it works.